# How to truncate a long string and add a tooltip for the complete string when hovered in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a mat-table in which a column value has a long string value , which is taking a lot of horizontal space . I want to truncate the string to a limit and let the user hover over it and see the complete string .

What is the keyword used for limiting the string value in the html ?

I tried creating a pipe limit but that didnt work for me .

Can anyone please help ?

PS - I edited the question because the previous limit pipe was not working for me

Comment: Easiest way, `<p [title]="text">{{text | limit: 40}}</p>` but I'm not sure if that's what you're after exactly so leaving as comment.

Comment: Yes something of that sort , but this pipe limit is not working inside angular mat table cell . Searching for an alternative to limiting and tooltip .

Comment: Ah oh that explains a bit more. Instead of limiting I think you're after just applying ellipsis [like this](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-make-css-ellipsis-work-on-a-table-cell.html) unless there's some specific reason to do the limiting.

Comment: No elipisng is not my aim , i just want to truncate if any long string in my table column , and show it as a tooltip .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try your own pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
 
@Pipe({
    name: 'truncate'
})
export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {

    /**
     * Transform the specified value
     * If the value is not specified, it is returned ''
     * If the size of the string is greater than the limit, it returns a substring of the desired size
     * If the size of the string is less than the limit, it returns the original string
     * @param value
     * @param size
     */
    transform(value: string, size: number = 10): string {
        if (!value) {
            return '';
        }
        const limit = size > 0 ? size : 10;
        return value.length > limit ? value.substring(0, limit) + '...' : value;
    }
}
```

and use this way to show full text in tooltip and truncate value on html text

```
<label [matTooltip]="descripcion ">{{descripcion  | truncate:50}}</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try `slice` instead of `limit`. Like this:

```
<button mat-raised-button [matTooltip]="Data">
  {{Data | slice:0:40 }}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the tooltip-part: If you have Angular Material integrated, you could use the [Material Tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip)

just like this:

```
<p [matTooltip]="text">{{text | limit : 40}}</p>
```

Comment: But as i mentioned in my question , The limit itself shows an error in the console .

Comment: Where have you changed @Tino?

Comment: That was an answer to another comment from chris, concerning a typo n my code example